# Empty connection header topic

Tags: ros, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a driver that reads the name of the incoming topic from the connection header.  When I publish data from a C++ node, it is always empty but when I use `rostopic pub` it works just fine.  Is there a way to ensure the connection header is populated?

Thanks,

-Tony

Edit for additional information

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

ROS:indigo 1.11.9

roscpp: 1.11.9-0trusty-20141029-0127-+0000

roscpp_core: 0.5.4-0trusty-20140724-0053-+0000

The subscriber is in C++ and is [here](https://github.com/smd-ros-devel/lynxmotion_ssc32/blob/master/src/ssc32_driver.cpp#L391)

Works with [python](https://gist.github.com/tonybaltovski/e1470fc1175b423ca5f4). Here is the [C++ node](https://gist.github.com/tonybaltovski/ac75f7e3273e7086a433)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200187/empty-connection-header-topic/) by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2549 on 2014-12-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Was recently fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/c672d411820ede2b62c3f1d9bd59cf3a8d771af4).

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the surface, this sounds like a bug in the roscpp publisher, but since this feature has existed in ROS for many years, that seems unlikely.

We're going to need quite a bit more information to debug this properly. You should edit your question to include:

- The version of ROS and the OS that you're using
- Which language the subscriber is written in
- The versions of the roscpp and roscpp_core packages that you're using
- The code for your C++ publisher which is giving you trouble

You may want to try writing the same publisher in python, to try to narrow down whether this is a difference between the python and C++ publishers, or if it's something wrong with the subscriber.

You may also want to try to reproduce this with the talker node from roscpp_tutorials and rospy_tutorials - those are "known good" nodes with well-defined behavior. If you can write a simple subscriber which reproduces this with the talker nodes, it should be easy to submit it as a bug report.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-12-30**:
Thanks Austin, I added the additional information.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-31**:
I don't see anything obviously wrong with any of that code. You should probably try to boil this down to a small subscriber program which reproduces the issue, and submit it as a bug report.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-31**:
Really though, the driver should probably be using an extra callback parameter for the controller name, instead of trying to extract the controller name from the topic name. This parameter can be passed by using `boost::bind()`

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-02**:
Odd that it works for python.  It seems like it should be able to extract the name from the topic. Do you mean that the callback's message should have a parameter containing the name of the controller?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-02**:
Should the issue be under `ros_comm` or `roscpp_core`?  I'll just stick to python for now since it works but I'd like to get this fixed.  Thanks for your help.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-03**:
roscpp is the public API, and it's part of ros_comm, so the issue should probably be filed there. It's the same set of developers on both repositories anyway.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-01-03**:
Will do, thanks!